Why this A* implementation works for 8-puzzle entries and not for 15-puzzle entries?
THE FULL CODE IS IN THE ANSWERS BELOW
I'm gonna dissect this problem I'm having completely, contextualizing the full program and what each part of it do, because I don't know which part is not functioning as it should. I will tell what it SHOULD do and which output should occur. The post is long.
Index

TDLR: I summarize what is going on.
Full implementation statement: I describe the full implementation of my A*.
What's going on: I comment about the behaviour of the implementation, how it should works and how it is behaviouring.
Hypothesis: I tell you guys what I think is going wrong.

1.TLDR: I have an C implementation of A* for a Puzzle Solver that is not optimized and works only for 8-Puzzle entries and doesn't work for 15-Puzzle entries. I can't find why in the code this is happening and if the problem is the Astar function or the minheap. The minheap has two rules. If g_value + h_value is smaller, then it goes first. Rule two is a tie breaker, where the highest g_value goes first. After I implemented the rule two, the alg got worse.
2.Full problem statement:
Hi, I'm working in a Puzzle Solver solver using A*. The solver receives a puzzle in a matrix format like this:
int startPuzzle[N][N] = {
        {0, 6, 1},
        {7, 4, 2},
        {3, 8, 5}};

N can be either 3 or 4, so it can solve 8-puzzles and 15-puzzles. 0 represents the blank space and a movement consists of swapping the 0 with other number in the tile.
For each possible state of the puzzle, I create a node for this state, which is represented like this:
// Structure definition for a puzzle node
typedef struct Entry
{
    int puzzle[N][N];
    struct Entry *next[MAX_NEIGHBORS];
    struct Entry *prev;
    float h_value; // Estimated cost to reach the goal state from this state
    int g_value;
} Entry;

*next is an array of neighbours, which are the possible states that you can reach from the currently state. For example, in the center space, you can do four movements, up, left, down and right. Therefore, you have four neighbours.
*prev is the father node, the node which this state made a movement to reach it.
h_value is a heuristic value, calculated using the Manhattan Distance.
The manhattan distance is calculated like this:
int manhattanDistance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    return abs(x2 - x1) + abs(y2 - y1);
}


void findNumberPosition(int puzzle[N][N], int num, int *x, int *y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (puzzle[i][j] == num)
            {
                *x = i;
                *y = j;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Função para calcular a distância de Manhattan total para o 8-puzzle
int totalManhattanDistance(int puzzle[N][N])
{
    int goal[N][N] = {
        {0, 1, 2},
        {3, 4, 5}, 
        {6, 7, 8}};
    int totalDistance = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (puzzle[i][j] != 0)
            { 
                int goalX, goalY;
                findNumberPosition(goal, puzzle[i][j], &goalX, &goalY);
                totalDistance += manhattanDistance(i, j, goalX, goalY);
            }
        }
    }
    return totalDistance;
}

It calculates the sum of the distances of each number from the goal. the great the distance from the goal position in the array, the greater is the manhattan distance.
g_value is the total value for reaching the state. Each movement has individually the cost of 1, and this value is summed from movement to movement.
Okay, so the Idea of A* is to choose the movement with the lower cost of h_value + g_value, right? How do we choose this movement? We use a Priority Queue to organize the states, where the smallest value goes first. This Priority Queue in reality is a Binary Min Heap, but I used the name priority queue because in pratice the we take the first in line and we organize prioritizing the lowest value.
Here is the implementation of the Priority Queue:
First the structure:
typedef struct
{
    Entry **heap;
    int size;
    int capacity;
} PriorityQueue;

We have an array of entries represented by a pointer of pointers, the size of the queue and its capacity.
PriorityQueue *createPriorityQueue(int capacity)
{
    PriorityQueue *pq = (PriorityQueue *)malloc(sizeof(PriorityQueue));
    pq->heap = (Entry **)malloc(capacity * sizeof(Entry *));
    pq->size = 0;
    pq->capacity = capacity;
    return pq;
}

void swap(Entry **a, Entry **b)
{
    Entry *temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

Here we have the initialization of the Queue values and a function that swap the entries inside the queue.
Now the fun part:
void enqueue(PriorityQueue *pq, Entry *entry)
{
    if (pq->size == pq->capacity)
    {
        printf("Priority Queue is full\n");
        return;
    }
    pq->heap[pq->size++] = entry;
    heapifyUp(pq, pq->size - 1);
}

Entry *dequeue(PriorityQueue *pq)
{
    if (pq->size == 0)
    {
        printf("Priority Queue is empty\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    Entry *entry = pq->heap[0];
    pq->heap[0] = pq->heap[pq->size - 1];
    pq->size--;

    heapifyDown(pq, 0); // Heapify down to maintain heap property

    return entry;
}

// Function to check if the deque is empty
bool isEmpty(PriorityQueue *pq)
{
    return pq->size == 0;
}

enqueue inserts a node inside the the queue and increases its sizes. After that, we use a function called heapifyUp to organize the queue.
dequeue deletes takes a node from the queue, decreases it sizes and reorganizes the queue with heapifyDown. We going to comment heapifyUp and Down shortly after.
isEmpty verifies if the Priority Queue is empty.
Now, let's see how the queue organizes itself by priority:
void heapifyUp(PriorityQueue *pq, int index)
{
    while (index > 0 && (pq->heap[index]->g_value + pq->heap[index]->h_value) < (pq->heap[(index - 1) / 2]->g_value + pq->heap[(index - 1) / 2]->h_value))
    {
        swap(&pq->heap[index], &pq->heap[(index - 1) / 2]);
        index = (index - 1) / 2;
    }
}

void heapifyDown(PriorityQueue *pq, int index)
{
    int smallest = index;
    int left = 2 * index + 1;
    int right = 2 * index + 2;

    if (left < pq->size && (pq->heap[left]->g_value + pq->heap[left]->h_value) < (pq->heap[smallest]->g_value + pq->heap[smallest]->h_value))
    {
        smallest = left;
    }

    if (right < pq->size && (pq->heap[right]->g_value + pq->heap[right]->h_value) < (pq->heap[smallest]->g_value + pq->heap[smallest]->h_value))
    {
        smallest = right;
    }

    

    if (smallest != index)
    {
        swap(&pq->heap[index], &pq->heap[smallest]);
        heapifyDown(pq, smallest);
    }
}

HeapifyUp
Functionality:
The function starts with a while loop that continues as long as two conditions are met:

The current element is not at the root of the heap (index > 0).
The current element's priority (sum of g_value and h_value) is less than the priority of its parent. The parent is represented as an index of index - 1/2

Inside the loop, it compares the priority of the current element with its parent. If the current element's priority is lower (indicating higher priority), it swaps the current element with its parent to satisfy the heap property.
After swapping, the index is updated to the parent index, and the loop continues until the element reaches its correct position in the heap or until it becomes the root of the heap.
Heap Property:
In this context, the heap property typically refers to the min-heap property, where the priority of a node is less than or equal to the priority of its children.
The priority is calculated as the sum of g_value and h_value.
HeapifyDown:
Functionality:

The function starts by initializing a variable smallest to the current index, indicating that initially, the current node is considered as the smallest.

It calculates the indices of the left and right children of the current node (left = 2 * index + 1 and right = 2 * index + 2).

It then checks if the left child exists (left < pq->size) and if its priority (sum of g_value and h_value) is less than the priority of the current smallest node. If so, it updates smallest to the left child index.

It similarly checks if the right child exists (right < pq->size) and if its priority is less than the priority of the current smallest node. If so, it updates smallest to the right child index.
If smallest is not equal to the current index, it means one of the children has a smaller priority, so it swaps the current node with the smallest child node to maintain the heap property.

After swapping, the function recursively calls itself on the new smallest index to continue heapifying down from that point.


Ok! Now we have a Priority Queue to organize the nodes we can visit using our movements and prioritizing them so we always go for the less expensive path.
But something is missing: We need to store the nodes we already visited, so we do not repeat them when we are expanding possible states. For that, we have a hash function:
// Function to calculate the hash value of a puzzle state
int hash(int puzzle[N][N])
{
    int hashValue = 0;

    // Iterate through the puzzle state and calculate the hash value
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            hashValue = 31 * hashValue + puzzle[i][j];
        }
    }

    return hashValue;
}

// Function to check if a puzzle state has been visited
bool isVisited(Entry *visited[], int puzzle[N][N])
{
    int hashValue = hash(puzzle);

    // Calculate the index in the visited array using the hash value
    int index = abs(hashValue) % 1000000;

    // Traverse the linked list at the index and check for the puzzle state
    Entry *current = visited[index];
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (areEqual(current->puzzle, puzzle))
            return true;
        current = current->next[0];
    }
    return false;
}

// Function to add a puzzle state to the visited nodes
void addToVisited(Entry *visited[], int puzzle[N][N])
{
    int hashValue = hash(puzzle);

    // Calculate the index in the visited array using the hash value
    int index = abs(hashValue) % 1000000;

    // Create a new node for the puzzle state
    Entry *newNode = (Entry *)malloc(sizeof(Entry));
    memcpy(newNode->puzzle, puzzle, sizeof(newNode->puzzle));
    newNode->next[0] = NULL;

    // Add the new node to the linked list at the index
    if (visited[index] == NULL)
    {
        visited[index] = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        Entry *current = visited[index];
        while (current->next[0] != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next[0];
        }
        current->next[0] = newNode;
    }
}

I will not go in details, since this hash function worked pretty well when I implemented BFS. But basically it generates a hash value for a puzzle state, check if this value is generated and add a new value if the hash value was not previously in the array of the hash.
Now we can finally check the A* implementation. Let's break into parts:

The Astar receives a puzzle as input. First, we initialize some values. emptyRow and EmptyCol are values I'm going to explain later. nodes is VERY important. It count how many nodes where generated while computing the algorithm. We gonna use it as a basis for the analysis later. breakBothLoops is a flag for going out of a loop composed of a while and a for. We initialize the Priority Queue and the hash table:

// Initialize goal
    int emptyRow, emptyCol;
    int nodes = 0;
    bool breakBothLoops = false;
    // Initialize the priority queue for A*
    PriorityQueue *pq = createPriorityQueue(MAX_SIZE);

    // Initialize the visited nodes array dynamically
    Entry **visited = (Entry **)calloc(1000000, sizeof(Entry *));
    if (visited == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


Next, we check if the startPuzzle is the goal. If it is not, we generate a node for it and add it to the Priority Queue:

int goal[N][N] = {
        {0, 1, 2},
        {3, 4, 5},
        {6, 7, 8}};

    if (areEqual(startPuzzle, goal))
    {
        printf("Start puzzle is already the goal.\n");
        return;
    }

    // Enqueue the initial puzzle state
    Entry *startEntry = (Entry *)malloc(sizeof(Entry));
    if (startEntry == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memcpy(startEntry->puzzle, startPuzzle, sizeof(startEntry->puzzle));
    startEntry->next[0] = NULL;
    startEntry->prev = NULL;
    startEntry->g_value = 0;
    startEntry->h_value = totalManhattanDistance(startEntry->puzzle);
    enqueue(pq, startEntry);
    addToVisited(visited, startPuzzle);


While the priority queue is not empty, we do the follow.


We take one entry from the queue, the smallest one.
We add it to nodes generated.
We use two arrays for representing the possible movement inside
For each of the possible movements, we see if the movement is inside the boundaries (if it's in the first tile of the puzzle, it can't go up).
If it is, we check if the possible movement state is the goal. If it is, we break the for loop and we use the flag to break the while loop.
If it isn't we check if the possible movement was already visited. If not, we generate a node with the g_value equals the father + 1 and we calculate the Manhattan Distance for the h_value. Then we enqueue the node and add it to the visited.

while (!isEmpty(pq))
    {
        // Dequeue a puzzle state
        Entry *currentEntry = dequeue(pq);
        nodes++;
        // Generate neighboring puzzle states and enqueue them if not visited
        // Define possible moves: up, down, left, right
        int dx[] = {-1, 0, 0, 1};                //-1 0 0 1
        int dy[] = {0, -1, 1, 0};                // 0 -1 1 0
        char moveNames[] = {'U', 'L', 'R', 'D'}; // For printing purposes
        findEmptyTile(currentEntry->puzzle, &emptyRow, &emptyCol);
        // Generate neighboring puzzle states
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NEIGHBORS; i++)
        {
            int newRow = emptyRow + dx[i];
            int newCol = emptyCol + dy[i];

            // Check if the new position is within bounds
            if (newRow >= 0 && newRow < N && newCol >= 0 && newCol < N)
            {
                // Create a new puzzle state by swapping the empty tile with its neighbor
                int newPuzzle[N][N];
                memcpy(newPuzzle, currentEntry->puzzle, sizeof(newPuzzle));
                swapTiles(&newPuzzle[emptyRow][emptyCol], &newPuzzle[newRow][newCol]); 

                // Check if the current puzzle state is the goal
                if (areEqual(newPuzzle, goal))
                {
                    printf("Goal puzzle reached!\n%d nodes generated! %d steps", nodes, currentEntry->h_value);
                    breakBothLoops = true;
                    break;
                }

                if (!isVisited(visited, newPuzzle))
                {
                    Entry *neighbor = (Entry *)malloc(sizeof(Entry));
                    memcpy(neighbor->puzzle, newPuzzle, sizeof(neighbor->puzzle));
                    neighbor->prev = currentEntry;
                    neighbor->next[0] = NULL;                                     // Set the next pointer corresponding to this move
                    neighbor->g_value = currentEntry->g_value + 1;                // Increment g-value
                    neighbor->h_value = totalManhattanDistance(neighbor->puzzle); // Calculate h-value
                    enqueue(pq, neighbor);
                    addToVisited(visited, newPuzzle);

}}} if (breakBothLoops)
                    break;


The full code is here:
/ Function for breadth-first search (BFS)
void Astar(int startPuzzle[N][N])
{
    // Initialize goal
    int emptyRow, emptyCol;
    int nodes = 0;
    bool breakBothLoops = false;
    // Initialize the priority queue for A*
    PriorityQueue *pq = createPriorityQueue(MAX_SIZE);

    // Initialize the visited nodes array dynamically
    Entry **visited = (Entry **)calloc(1000000, sizeof(Entry *));
    if (visited == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int goal[N][N] = {
        {0, 1, 2},
        {3, 4, 5},
        {6, 7, 8}};

    if (areEqual(startPuzzle, goal))
    {
        printf("Start puzzle is already the goal.\n");
        return;
    }

    // Enqueue the initial puzzle state
    Entry *startEntry = (Entry *)malloc(sizeof(Entry));
    if (startEntry == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memcpy(startEntry->puzzle, startPuzzle, sizeof(startEntry->puzzle));
    startEntry->next[0] = NULL;
    startEntry->prev = NULL;
    startEntry->g_value = 0;
    startEntry->h_value = totalManhattanDistance(startEntry->puzzle);
    enqueue(pq, startEntry);
    addToVisited(visited, startPuzzle);

    // Perform ASTAR
    while (!isEmpty(pq))
    {
        // Dequeue a puzzle state
        Entry *currentEntry = dequeue(pq);
        nodes++;
        // Generate neighboring puzzle states and enqueue them if not visited
        // Define possible moves: up, down, left, right
        int dx[] = {-1, 0, 0, 1};                //-1 0 0 1
        int dy[] = {0, -1, 1, 0};                // 0 -1 1 0
        char moveNames[] = {'U', 'L', 'R', 'D'}; // For printing purposes
        findEmptyTile(currentEntry->puzzle, &emptyRow, &emptyCol);
        // Generate neighboring puzzle states
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NEIGHBORS; i++)
        {
            int newRow = emptyRow + dx[i];
            int newCol = emptyCol + dy[i];

            // Check if the new position is within bounds
            if (newRow >= 0 && newRow < N && newCol >= 0 && newCol < N)
            {
                // Create a new puzzle state by swapping the empty tile with its neighbor
                int newPuzzle[N][N];
                memcpy(newPuzzle, currentEntry->puzzle, sizeof(newPuzzle));
                swapTiles(&newPuzzle[emptyRow][emptyCol], &newPuzzle[newRow][newCol]); 

                // Check if the current puzzle state is the goal
                if (areEqual(newPuzzle, goal))
                {
                    printf("Goal puzzle reached!\n%d nodes generated! %d steps", nodes, currentEntry->h_value);
                    breakBothLoops = true;
                    break;
                }

                if (!isVisited(visited, newPuzzle))
                {
                    Entry *neighbor = (Entry *)malloc(sizeof(Entry));
                    memcpy(neighbor->puzzle, newPuzzle, sizeof(neighbor->puzzle));
                    neighbor->prev = currentEntry;
                    neighbor->next[0] = NULL;                                     // Set the next pointer corresponding to this move
                    neighbor->g_value = currentEntry->g_value + 1;                // Increment g-value
                    neighbor->h_value = totalManhattanDistance(neighbor->puzzle); // Calculate h-value
                    enqueue(pq, neighbor);
                    addToVisited(visited, newPuzzle);
                }
            }
        }
        // Free the memory allocated for the dequeued node
        if (breakBothLoops)
                    break;
        free(currentEntry);
    }

    // Free memory allocated for visited nodes
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        Entry *current = visited[i];
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            Entry *temp = current;
            current = current->next[0];
            free(temp);
        }
    }

    // Free the memory allocated for the visited array
    free(visited);
}

3.What's going on?
In short, for 15-Puzzle it doesn't compute and crashes.
I have some tests entries of states of 8-puzzles and how many nodes should I generate. For the following tests goes like this:
Initial Puzzle State:
0 6 1
7 4 2
3 8 5
Expected: 91 nodes.
Generated: 101 nodes.

Initial Puzzle State:
5 0 2
6 4 8
1 7 3
Expected: 612 nodes.
Generated: 495 nodes.


Initial Puzzle State:
2 4 7
0 3 6
8 1 5
Expected: 511 nodes.
Generated: 504 nodes.

Despite having better performance in the last two, it was slightly worse in the first test. Only 10 nodes of difference. And I don't know why! I have some hipothesis that I will comment short after.
So the question is: Why is performing worse in some and better in others? And why it didn't work with 15-Puzzle states?
4.Hypohesis
THE PRIORITY QUEUE IS WRONG.
I think something in the implementation of it it's not working. Most important, it has not any tie breaker for heuristics with the same value. I need to prioritize the node following this prioritization:
⟨min: value −f, min: value −h, LIFO⟩.
So i tried something like in heapifyDown:
    if (left < pq->size && (pq->heap[left]->g_value + pq->heap[left]->h_value) == (pq->heap[smallest]->g_value + pq->heap[smallest]->h_value) && (pq->heap[left]->h_value) < (pq->heap[smallest]->h_value)
    {
        smallest = left;
    }

    if (right < pq->size && (pq->heap[right]->g_value + pq->heap[right]->h_value) == (pq->heap[smallest]->g_value + pq->heap[smallest]->h_value)&& (pq->heap[right]->h_value) < (pq->heap[smallest]->h_value))
    {
        smallest = right;
    }

Unfortunately, the A* become worse, expanding more nodes. Perhaps I didn't set the tie breakers correctly?
The A* IS WRONG:
I followed each step of the pseudocode accordingly, so I doubt the problem resides here.
Anyway, thanks for reading so far and reach me out if you know what can I do to improve the A*.
I tried to fix the tie breakers like i mentioned before and didn't work out.

Where does it crash? Once you know that you can try figuring out why. A debugger is the tool to use here. If you have AddressSanitizer available compile with that. -fsanitize=address,undefined With the code all broken up into snippets I'm not going to attempt to piece it together.

You've [obviously] put a lot of effort into your question. But, splitting the code into separate blocks adds to the narrative but doesn't help us debug your code. Despite what the MRE page says (about small separate blocks), the program can't be downloaded, compiled, and run. If there were only a few, we might be able to download the blocks and concatenate them into a single .c file that we can use. But, there are just too many. And, they're not in compilable order.

We would really like an MRE. For C, we would like a single .c file [with (e.g.) #include <stdio.h>]. But, no (e.g.) #include "myprogram.h" (For those, copy-and-paste in the .h contents.) For runtime errors, it should compile cleanly. We should be able to download, build, and run it on our local systems [if we so choose].

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function main and all #include directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem (which should preferably be hard-coded into the program). This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

I added the full code with a main that runs the example. If you run it by its own, you can see how it behaves. Is that what you guys were asking for?

The code you added doesn't compile. It is missing a } on the startPuzzle declaration. https://godbolt.org/z/6YdhMx1xq You also added it as an answer but it isn't one. You should edit the question. The hash function has undefined behavior because it overflows a signed integer.

"Why is performing worse in some and better in others? And why it didn't work with 15-Puzzle states?" These are two different questions. Please focus on one only, and please add your debugging efforts to explain the difference between expected and generated states. For the 15-puzzle there is a clear error: the goal state has not been adapted to 4x4. It will never be found. Side note: sometimes you print the h_value as float, sometimes as int. Why is it a float anyway? Manhattan distance is an int...

i copy pasted your code and with N as 4, i do not see crash. It is difficult to say unless some missing code is also provided in question. findEmptyTiles() and areEqual() are not in the question. I put default implementation in those and no issues seen. Some changes made were removing bool with int and startPuzzle renamed as stPuzzle because there is name conflict for same as parameter to Astar(). Also I took out goal and made global variable. I suspect findEmptyTile() as crash cause though it is wrong to say considering that code is not in question. It is helpful to put puzzle description. I could not figure out how do you define empty tile in 3x3 or 4x4 matrix, so I returned x,y for 0,0 for findEmptyTile(). To get better result like last two test cases you got solution in lesser nodes, the dx and dy array elements order if you switch and experiment with it, may be you may get better result with some ordering. Though one way is to not return after goal is found but start with new start condition and it is possible that start condition can be for any intermediate node with dx,dy.
